# Play #canvas #html5 when scrolling down the page

Tags: javascript, html, flash, canvas, scroll

I have a HTML5 canvas exported from Flash.
I would like to play canvas when you scroll down the window so it's not autoplay.
Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: We need more information. How did you export from Flash? Did you export Flash frames as images--if so you would sequentially draw those images on the canvas. Did you convert Flash as3 to javascript--if so you would run that javascript during the scroll events.

Comment: Hi,
it was exported as HTML5 Canvas.
http://www.adobe.com/inspire/2014/02/flash-html5-canvas.html